# How To Convert Result Table to JSON in MySQL with Multiple Table Join

Tags: mysql, json, json-arrayagg

I have MySql Query like this:

```
SELECT product_list.id AS listId,
       product_list.class AS listClass,
       product.prod_name AS prodName,
       product.prod_url AS prodUrl,
       product.prod_overview AS prodOverview,
       product_img.list_prod340x340 AS prodListImg,
       MIN(pricelist.price) AS price
  FROM (((product_list 
  JOIN product_img ON product_list.id = product_img.prod_list_id) 
  JOIN product     ON product_list.id = product.prod_list_id) 
  JOIN pricelist   ON product.id = pricelist.prod_id)
 GROUP BY listId, listClass, prodName, prodUrl, prodOverview, prodListImg
 ORDER BY product_list.id, price
```

I want to get result in JSON format, how can i get there?

Comment: Can you please reconsider why you needed those brackets within the part after the `FROM` clause ..?

Comment: dunno, just following the tutorial from w3school